# Validar multiples imagenes con javascript

Tags: javascript, html5

Necesito hacer una validación de múltiples imagenes que voy subiendo al formulario, si bien puedo hacerlo con una función por cada input, no se como hacerlo con un array en javascript para todos los inputs type="file". Es decir la misma función javascript "fileValidation()" para todos los inputs, ademas necesito insertarlos en la base de datos, He visto varios ejemplos pero no puedo lograrlo . Adjunto codigo

// Html

```
<form  action="data/insertcheck.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center" >

  <label for="imagen1" class="btn">Seleccione Imagen</label>
  <input  type="file" style="visibility:hidden;"  name="imagen" id="imagen1" onchange="fileValidation()"/>

  <div class="ima" id="imagePre1">

  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center" >

  <label for="imagen2" class="btn">Seleccione imagen</label>
<input  type="file" style="visibility:hidden;" name="imagen" id="imagen2" onchange="fileValidation2()"/>

  <div class="ima" id="imagePre2" >

  </div>
</div>
<div  class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center" >

  <label for="imagen3" class="btn">Seleccione imagen</label>
  <input  type="file" style="visibility:hidden;" name="imagen" id="imagen3" onchange="fileValidation3()"/>

  <div class="ima" id="imagePre3">

  </div>
</div>

 <div class="col-md-8">
                    <a id="back_paso_b" href="" class="btn btn-info" >Regresar</a>
              <input type="submit" value="Guardar" name="btncambiar" id="btncambiar" class="btn btn-success btn-primary">
          </div>

        </div>

      </form>
```

//validación y previsualización en javascript de imagenes

```
 <script>

function fileValidation(){

    var fileInput = document.getElementById('imagen1');

    var filePath = fileInput.value;
    var allowedExtensions = /(.jpg|.jpeg)$/i;
    if(!allowedExtensions.exec(filePath)){
        alert('Por favor seleccione archivo de extensión .jpeg/.jpg únicamente.');
        fileInput.value = '';
        return false;
    }else{
        //Image preview
        if (fileInput.files && fileInput.files[0]) {

            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                document.getElementById('imagePre1').innerHTML = '<img src="'+e.target.result+'" style="width:200px; height:200px;"/>';

            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(fileInput.files[0]);
        }
    }
}


function fileValidation2(){
    var fileInput = document.getElementById('imagen2');
    var filePath = fileInput.value;
    var allowedExtensions = /(.jpg|.jpeg)$/i;
    if(!allowedExtensions.exec(filePath)){
        alert('Por favor seleccione archivo de extensión .jpeg/.jpg únicamente.');
        fileInput.value = '';
        return false;
    }else{
        //Image preview
        if (fileInput.files && fileInput.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                document.getElementById('imagePre2').innerHTML = '<img src="'+e.target.result+'" style="width:200px; height:200px;"/>';
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(fileInput.files[0]);
        }
    }
}

function fileValidation3(){
    var fileInput = document.getElementById('imagen3');
    var filePath = fileInput.value;
    var allowedExtensions = /(.jpg|.jpeg)$/i;
    if(!allowedExtensions.exec(filePath)){
        alert('Por favor seleccione archivo de extensión .jpeg/.jpg únicamente.');
        fileInput.value = '';
        return false;
    }else{
        //Image preview
        if (fileInput.files && fileInput.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                document.getElementById('imagePre3').innerHTML = '<img src="'+e.target.result+'" style="width:200px; height:200px;"/>';
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(fileInput.files[0]);
        }
    }
}


</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba lo siguiente en el html:

poner el atributo onChange="fileValidation2(numero_imagen)" en cada input
ejemplo:

```
<input  type="file" style="visibility:hidden;" name="imagen1" id="imagen1" onchange="fileValidation(1)"/>
<input  type="file" style="visibility:hidden;" name="imagen2" id="imagen2" onchange="fileValidation(2)"/>
```

De ese modo en el javascript solo debes cambiar la funcion fileValidation para que reciba los números

```
function fileValidation(numero){
// La entrada seria el número de la imagen
var fileInput = document.getElementById('imagen'+numero);
// En el imgPre haces lo mismo, asumiendo que usas el mismo número para la imagen y su correspondiente Pre
document.getElementById('imagePre'+numero).innerHTML = '<img src="'+e.target.result+'" style="width:200px; height:200px;"/>';
```

}

Por último una recomendación para evitarte otro dolor de cabeza. En html el atributo name, solo es uno. si hay más con el mismo nombre, solo se enviará el último al backend.
En resumen, usa uno distinto en cada input
name="imagen1", name="imagen2"

O si lo que quieres es enviar un solo array puedes hacer algo como esto:

name="imagen[0]", name="imagen[1]"